# How to perform Sequential Method Execution in ngOnInit one after another

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Angular15. I have two methods in app.component.ts “ngOnInit()” as below.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
this.getToken();
this.UserLoggedIn();  }
```

I want to call above two functions in one after another Sequential order.
First i want to run "this.getToken()" after this need to run "this.UserLoggedIn()".

```
public getToken(): void {
    this.LoggedIn = false
    let params = (new URL(this.redirectURL).searchParams)
    let value = params.get("value")
      value = value? value : ''
      this.authService.getGCDMToken(value).subscribe((content:any)=>{
        let matchOfCookies = new Map<string, any>();
        matchOfCookies.set('access_token', content.access_token)
        content.access_token ? this.LoggedIn = true : this.LoggedIn = false
        const AccessToken = matchOfCookies.get("access_token");     
      })
  }

private UserLoggedIn(): void {
      const userName = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
      if (userName) {
        this.store.dispatch(login({username: userName}));
      } else {
        this.authService.isUserLogged()
        .subscribe((data) => {
          if (data) {
            this.store.dispatch(login({username: data}));
          } else {
            this.store.dispatch(logout());
          }

          if (this.cookieService.get('gcdm-accessToken')) {
            sessionStorage.setItem('username', data);
            console.log('set session username:', data);
          }
        },(error: any) => {
          console.error('UserLogged error', error);
        });         
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use "then" operator.

this.getToken().then(()=>this.UserLoggedIn());

But it trows error like :"Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.".

Answer (score 0):

your getToken does not return a promise that is why u cannot use then.

```
public getToken(): Observable<any> {
    this.LoggedIn = false;
    let params = (new URL(this.redirectURL).searchParams);
    let value = params.get("value");
    value = value ? value : '';
    return this.authService.getGCDMToken(value).pipe(
        tap((content: any) => {
            let matchOfCookies = new Map<string, any>();
            matchOfCookies.set('access_token', content.access_token);
            content.access_token ? this.LoggedIn = true : this.LoggedIn = false;
            const AccessToken = matchOfCookies.get("access_token");
        })
    );
}
```

then use pipe to call tghe user after getToken()

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getToken().pipe(
        tap(() => this.UserLoggedIn())
    ).subscribe();
}
```